# buffer issue | mongoose response even when mongodb is closed

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose, angular-universal

I am having trouble with mongoosejs, nodejs, mongoDB and expressjs. I dunno which one is causing the issue.

**What I am doing.**

- Make API call to expressjs end point, which is using mongoose to save
  data to mongodb.
- Server take data from API call.
- Save the data to the MongoDB.

**Issue**

- The mongoDB is not running.
- After the data is saved to (I dunno where and why.), I get
  objectID(_ID) and other fields which I am saving.*(console.log() when save success)*
- I even set the buffering OFF.

Totally confused here about

1. how is data saving?
2. Where is data saving?
3. How am I getting ObjectID?
4. How to access this data?

   Using [Angular-universal](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) with expressjs and mongoose. All the settings are default except buffering. I tried few other things but still facing the problem.

**end Point**

```
dataTable.save(function(err, payment){
    if(err){
        return res.redirect(301, someurl);
    }
    return res.redirect(301, someotherurl);
});
```